# A request header field is too long for cookies generated by STS

Tags: iis, cookies, http-headers, .net-6.0, iis-6

I have an external IdP, where I am not in control of the number of groups/roles. (Azure AD) And the header "Cookie" that is generated by STS (Ws Fed) exceeds the limit.

"Bad Request - Header Field Too Long
HTTP Error 400. A request header field is too long."

System: .NET6 Web App+ IIS 6

Already tried:

- added `<system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16777210" maxRequestHeadersTotalSize="131068"/></system.web>` to web.config
- added to web.config

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="16777210">
      <headerLimits>
        <add header="Cookie" sizeLimit="131068" />
      </headerLimits>
     </requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

- defined *MaxFieldLength* and *MaxRequestBytes* (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters)
- added

```
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
  options.MaxRequestBodyBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

I was able to make it work on Kestrel: `kestrelOptions.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = int.MaxValue`, but I need to make it work with IIS.

Comment: [Pls refer this doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-http-400-errors/ba-p/347601), if you still facing the same issue, you need to use high version IIS, like IIS10.

Comment: @JasonPan IIS10 will not help. Http.sys has still a lower limit than 100KB for each header field and the cookie is bigger than that.